# Static class member is not shared between different users on different IP

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I have written a static class and suppose to share it's members between all sessions. it works for all the browsers running on the same cumputer but the data is not shared between different users from different location. my website is written with ASP.NET

this is my class

```
public static class GlobalPool
{
    public static List<string> OnlineUsers;
}
```

and I instantiate the OnlineUSers property in Global.asax as

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    GlobalPool.OnlineUsers = new List<string>(100);
}
```

I add username whenever a user logs into my website:

```
public void Login(int aMemberSerial) 
{ 
    User = new MemberDataAccess().Read(aMemberSerial); 
    new MemberDataAccess().Login(User); 
    GlobalPool.OnlineUsers.Add(User.Username); 
    Message = PostBusiness.NewPost(User); 
}
```

Comment: Just to correct, I'm pretty sure its not shared between all users, its shared for an entire application domain, so in a web farm scenario its per server

Comment: how are things deployed, single server? where are you actually assigning a value to it and how do you know its not being persisted?

Comment: i uploaded my webpages on my hosting, using FTP. I don't think it is spread-ed on multiple server. Actually I assign GlobalPool.OnlineUsers in global.asax (Application_Start) and when a user log on to my protal, I add it's username to OnlineUsers. If I log-on to portan in different browsers on my computer, (1 chrome, 1 safari and 1 IE) then I check it from FireFox, I see all 3 users (using a page that dumps OnlineUsers list), but from my iPhone, I can't see them. Also my friend cannot see them from his home. likely if my friend log-on to portal using 3 browsers he can see them but I can't

Comment: provide the code where you add the user name to the list

Comment: from a cursory glance it looks ok, what host are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is not robust code. ASP.NET application routinely recycle (the App Pool) and so all your data will go away. 
The best way to approach this is to store the list in a database, and when a Session expires, remove that user from the data store.

Comment: I have implemented it in different ways but still like to know the answer. besides the recycling app pool, it should work w/o any problem. why it doesn't?